# iOS Safari Content Blocker "ignore-previous-rules" not working

Tags: javascript, ios, json, regex, safari-content-blocker

The desired functionality is for my content blocker is to hide a div with class `._mqsb` on every page on youtube, not including an url that contains `youtube.com/results` somewhere

The first rule works fine, hiding every `._mqsb` on every page with domain youtube.com

The second rule is supposed to ignore that rule whenever the domain is youtube.com and the URL contains `results` somewhere. But it doesn't seem to ignore the previous code, when I'm on https://m.youtube.com/results?q=eric+andre&sm=1 or any other search query.

This is the code in my blockerList.json:

```
{
    "trigger": {
        "url-filter": ".*",
        "if-domain": ["*youtube.com"]
    },
    "action": {
        "type": "css-display-none",
        "selector": "._mqsb"
    }
},
{
    "trigger": {
        "url-filter": ".*results.*",
        "if-domain": ["*youtube.com"]
    },
    "action": {
        "type": "ignore-previous-rules"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you invert the rules so that the second one has priority on the first one?

Comment: Nope, there's no priority attribute in safari content blockers

Comment: Here's their rule documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Extensions/Conceptual/ContentBlockingRules/CreatingRules/CreatingRules.html

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Comment: this was a long time ago, don't remember